# Stream a Video URL to Apple TV

Tags: appletv, airplay, streaming

I know that, for example, when I'm playing a video in YouTube on my iPhone then I AirPlay it to Apple TV, iPhone simply pass video link to Apple TV than iPhone works only as remote (in fact, turning iPhone's wifi off, Apple TV will keep playing video).

So is there a way, even with Mac, to give to Apple TV an URL then look it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple will support it natively in Safari from El Capitan!! (only with HTML5+)
http://www.apple.com/osx/elcapitan-preview/